# Retrofit jar and retrofit Gson converter factory error: Duplicate class

Tags: android, retrofit2, implementation

I'm starting to learn and practice using **retrofit**. I used the jar file on their website and included it in the libs folder. (It's the first time I use a jar file for libs)

When creating the RetrofitInstance file, and trying to use the `.addConverterFactory` The GsonConverterFactory doesn't appear.
If I add the implementation manually for the GsonConverter and I rebuild the project, errors appear saying that there are many (so many) duplicated files

```
Duplicate class com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter found in modules jetified-gson-2.8.5 (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5) and jetified-gson-2.8.6 (gson-2.8.6.jar)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.ExclusionStrategy found in modules jetified-gson-2.8.5 (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5) and jetified-gson-2.8.6 (gson-2.8.6.jar)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.FieldAttributes found in modules jetified-gson-2.8.5 (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5) and jetified-gson-2.8.6 (gson-2.8.6.jar)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy found in modules jetified-gson-2.8.5 (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5) and jetified-gson-2.8.6 (gson-2.8.6.jar)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy$1 found in modules jetified-gson-2.8.5 (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5) and jetified-gson-2.8.6 (gson-2.8.6.jar)
```

and so on.

I assume the problem is that the retrofit.jar already contains the GsonCOnverter (or something like that)

I know I can use these implementations directly instead of the jar file and not have problems

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
```

So my questions are while using the jar file, is there a way to use the GsonConverterFactory? and if not, how can I implement the `'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'`

These are the implementations in build.gradle:

```
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
//    retrofit
    implementation files('libs\\retrofit-2.9.0.jar')
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"
//    logging interceptor
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0")
```

This is the class:

```
class RetrofitInstance {

    companion object {
        private val retrofit by lazy {
            val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .build()

            Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
//                 GsonConverterFactory throws unresolved reference
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This out it works for me

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.2'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I want to do is not use the direct implementation `implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'` but to use the jar file that, when added as a library, adds this `implementation files('libs\\retrofit-2.9.0.jar')` automatically